# sed unknown command on windows cmd

Tags: sed

I just have to install a software cvxopt for a project and the instructions tell me to do this:

Remove all instances of ‘-mno-cygwin’ from c:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py using the command:

```
sed 's/-mno-cygwin//g' -i'.bak' c:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py
```

Every time I try to run the command , it says unknown command ' ' '.
I don't know what sed is , I just want to install cvxopt. I have been struggling with it for the last 2 hours. Please Help!

Comment: If you're running this in a CMD shell, use double quotes -- CMD doesn't understand single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

Firstly, the `-i` option doesn't work on all sed versions for Windows. It allows in-place editing. If yours doesn't, create an intermediate file like this and then overwrite your original if/when you are happy with it.

```
cd \Python27\Lib\distutils
sed "s/-mno-cygwin//g" cygwinccompiler.py   > x.tmp
del cygwinccompiler.py
ren x.tmp cygwinccompiler.py
```

Secondly, Windows doesn't understand single quotes, so use double quotes like this:

```
cd \Python27\Lib\distutils
sed "s/-mno-cygwin//g" -i".bak" cygwinccompiler.py
```